# How to used a blank delimiter when exporting CSV

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to export crystal report into csv but withouter a delimter character around fields,

here is a snipper of my code:

```
ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions();
exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.CharacterSeparatedValues;


DiskFileDestinationOptions DiskFileDestinationOpt = ExportOptions.CreateDiskFileDestinationOptions();
DiskFileDestinationOpt.DiskFileName = filename;
exportOpts.ExportDestinationOptions = DiskFileDestinationOpt;


CharacterSeparatedValuesFormatOptions csvOptions = new CharacterSeparatedValuesFormatOptions();
csvOptions.Delimiter = "";
csvOptions.SeparatorText = "";
exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = csvOptions;


crystalReportDoc.Export(exportOpts);
```

the problem is whenever I use an empty string for the delimiter property, crystal report will use the default double quote character in the result csv file.

can someone please assist on how to export a csv document with a blank delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a blank delimiter, it's not a csv file. (Comma-separated value) You're probably looking for more of a "Text" file type.

Comment: what I wan is: field1,field2,field3 is instead of "field1","field2","field3"

Comment: It's possible vial the the csv export gui, bust doesn't seems to work in C#

Comment: Oh, so you're looking to do .csv without quotes? Maybe that's a field in csvOptions?

Comment: yes the field is csvOptions.Delimiter, but it is not working when the delimiter is blank or null